# Failure to install slice-and-join .scm in Gimp 2.8

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, ubuntu-16.04, gimp

Using GIMP 2.8 on Ubuntu 16.04
Have downloaded the slice-and-join.scm script but when I try to save it to /usr/share/docs/gimp-data I get an error telling me I don't have permission.
I have read the dire warnings about security when using chmod and am worried that I may screw things up!
I really need to 
a. Read whats already in gimp-data, and,
b. Get this script working, 
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You should install scripts in the `scripts` subdirectory of your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/), which normally is `~/.gimp-2.8/scripts`(*). Note the leading dot in `.gimp-2.8` so don't forget to check the "hidden files".

(*) in case you need, the python scripts are technically plug-ins so go in `~/.gimp-2.8/plugins` (and must have th executable bit set).

Comment: Thankyou. ~/.gimp-2.8 now found and the script inserted in /scripts. As this doesn't give any result does your 2(*) in case you need, the python scripts are technically plug-ins so go in ~/.gimp-2.8/plugins (and must have th executable bit set)." mean I should put it in /plugins  - instead or as well?

Comment: Python just mentioned for reference, not too pertinent here. What do you mean by "No result"? Maybe the script is in some unexpected menu location, easy to find by inspecting the source code.

Comment: have put slice-and-join into both ~/.gimp2.8/scripts and /plugins but can only access it by Gimp-Filters-ATG-Image slice.  This produces first a selection screen but selecting OK on this gives an error " Image Slice Message -Error while executing script-fu-image-slice  Error:(<unknown>:144419854) write:argument 2 must be: output port"    Sorry for length of this comment but don't know how to add screenshots to a comment.

Comment: Actually just very buggy code. It append the Gimp data directory to any directory your give in the parameter dialog. So, when asked to use `/tmp`, it tries to open `/tmp\home/me/Sandbox/Image.jpg.rcm`. The file open fails, this isn't checked, and the ensuing write fails (the *write:argument 2 must be: output port* message, because it tries to write to #f (false))... In addition all the directory names processing uses hard-coded backslashes, so that's a Windows-only script.

Comment: So, that could perhaps work after a debugging session by a decent programmer. In the meantime, you'll find plenty of other Gimp scripts that do the same.

Comment: Thank you xenoid,  I won't waste any more time on it. I very much appreciate your help, thanks again.